# Make gridview fill horizontally

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to make a list with a `GridLayout` that has two *rows* and scrolls *horizontally*. My problem is that the gridview automatically adds views from top to bottom across the screen (*Vertically*) instead of filling an entire row before filling the next column (*Horizontally*).

**Images of what I'm talking about:**

[image: What Happens]

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
```

**auto_fit** Display as many columns as possible to fill the available space.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [recent-images](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) Library. It provides horizontal gridview(one row). Just add this library dependency and put below code in your xml.

```
<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E8E8E8"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:columnWidth="70dp"
app:rowHeight="70dp"
app:numColumns="auto_fit"
app:numRows="auto_fit"
app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
app:gravity="center"/>
```